# How to match different ids within a single data set in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

A sample of my data is

```html
df1 <- read.table(text = " id1  time    id2 gender  id3 group   id4 house
123 12  141 F   13  1   156 A
141 19  144 F   144 1   123 A
144 22  123 M   123 1   141 M
168 14  13  M   141 2   144 M
156 13  168 M   168 2   13  Q
13  11  156 F   156 2   168 Q

", header = TRUE)
```

I want to get the following outcome. For example, id123, time= 12, Gender=M, group=1, house= A, by looking at other ids

```html
df1 <- read.table(text = " id   time    gender  group   house
123 12  M   1   A
141 19  F   2   M
144 22  F   1   M
168 14  M   2   Q
156 13  F   2   A
13  11  M   1   Q
", header = TRUE)
```

I have tried left_join, but I struggled to get the outcome of interest

```html
df1 <- left_join(id2,id3,id4 by = "id1")
```

Comment: Not clear about the logic.  Are you trying to merge them trogether

Comment: can you explain the logic for getting the second output? I mean are you looking to remove duplicate rows?

Comment: My doubt is that why the 'group' and 'house' only changed in the expected while 'time' remains the same

Comment: depends on understanding the logic correctly

Comment: I was thinking that the different columns are based on different datasets i.e. ` list(df1 %>% select(id = id1, gender), df1 %>% select(id = id2, group), df1 %>% select(id = id3, house)) %>% reduce(left_join)`, but it is not the output you showed as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the folks confused here because your table is in an unusual format. Typically in R, we expect one variable per column and one observation per row. What you have is effectively four tables stuck side-by-side, where id1, id2, id3 and id4 are all actually just "id". So effectively, you are looking to left join columns 3:4 to columns 1:2, then left join columns 5:6 to that, and so on.

I'll show one way of doing that, then maybe some of the smart folks here can show you a better way:

```r
library(dplyr)

df_list <- lapply(list(1:2, 3:4, 5:6, 7:8), function(x) df1[x])
df_list <- lapply(df_list, function(x) {names(x)[1] <- "id"; x})

df2 <- df_list[[1]] %>% 
         left_join(df_list[[2]]) %>% 
         left_join(df_list[[3]]) %>% 
         left_join(df_list[[4]])

df2
#>    id time gender group house
#> 1 123   12      M     1     A
#> 2 141   19      F     2     M
#> 3 144   22      F     1     M
#> 4 168   14      M     2     Q
#> 5 156   13      F     2     A
#> 6  13   11      M     1     Q
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

It seems like we need a `match` for different 'id' columns and corresponding 'group', 'gender' etc columns

```
nm1 <- c('id1', 'time', 'gender', 'group', 'house')
out1 <- transform(df1, gender = gender[match(id1, id2)], 
          group = group[match(id1, id3)],
           house = house[match(id1, id4)])[nm1]
names(out1)[1] <- 'id'

out1
#   id time gender group house
#1 123   12      M     1     A
#2 141   19      F     2     M
#3 144   22      F     1     M
#4 168   14      M     2     Q
#5 156   13      F     2     A
#6  13   11      M     1     Q
```

---

In addition to the above `base R`, an alternative option to @AllanCameron's solution would be to `split` subset of columns based on the occurrence of 'id' column (`split.default`), then change the first column name to 'id' and apply `left_join` within `reduce`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df1 %>%
     split.default(cumsum(startsWith(names(.), "id"))) %>% 
     map(~ rename_at(.x, 1, ~ 'id')) %>% 
     reduce(left_join, by = 'id')
#     id time gender group house
#1 123   12      M     1     A
#2 141   19      F     2     M
#3 144   22      F     1     M
#4 168   14      M     2     Q
#5 156   13      F     2     A
#6  13   11      M     1     Q
```

Comment: sorry I didn't notice you had posted this answer when I posted mine. Looks like we came to the same conclusion in a different way.

Comment: @AllanCameron Actually, you posted this solution.  I had something similar in the comments, but at that time I didn't use the column order corrrectly.  Yours is original, so i referenced your name

Comment: @AllanCameron I hope you don't mind using your logic on my post

Comment: Not at all akrun, Nice to see other implementations. Mine felt a bit clunky.